# Two different jQuery UI themes on the same page

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

I want to have two different jQuery UI accordion menus on the same page, but I want them to have different themes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. [The jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming) has a robust and complete theming solution. Just give your accordions separate CSS classes - jQuery UI classes are semantic in nature - and off you go! Let me know if you'd like an example.

EDIT: There are many different ways to do this, depending on what your needs are. See the bottom part of [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Accordion#options) for more information on how to use theme-ing with the accordion

Answer (score 2):

According to the article [Using Multiple jQuery UI Themes on a Single Page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/) from the Filament Group, it is possible to provide a CSS Scope when a theme is downloaded that will allow you to specify use of alternate themes on a single page. There is also a link to [a demo page](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/multiple-themes/).

Disclaimer: I have not tried doing this myself, but it does look promising.