# Using two dfferent jQuery UI themes in the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, themeroller

I want to use two different themes - Vader and UI Darkness for two different UI applications in the same page. Any idea how to do it? I followed the links provided at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988078/two-different-jquery-ui-themes-on-the-same-page), but I couldn't follow their methods.

Comment: what was the problem? doesn't the scope option (under Advanced Theme Settings above the download button) work? http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: No no, it's working now. Thanks. I couldn't find the Advanced Theme Settings button initially.